# Migration from spring 1.2.8 to spring 3.1 and Hibernate 3.1 to 4.0

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am looking for a spring 1.2.8 to spring 3.1 migration guide and Hibernate migration guide. I could not find relevant info on Google. Please share with me if there are useful articles.

I got the following error when I replace spring 1.2.8 jar with spring 3.1 jars.

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MANUAL
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:102)

Comment: First of all, don't use any class from org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 if you're using Hibernate 4. As the package name indicates, these classes are for Hibernate 3, and not 4. Use the classes from org.springframework.orm.hibernate4

Comment: But, I have not yet added Hibernate 4 jars. First I am trying to fix all spring related issues. So, I have replace spring 1.2.8 jar with spring 3.1 jars.

Comment: @Veerendra see the first paragraph of my answer, it explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Hibernate 3.2 or newer first!
See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7008 (last comment)

*It is the first answer by Google if you google for "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MANUAL at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:102)"*

---

If you use Hibernate 4, then you should use the `new org.springframework.orm.hibernate4` package (introduced in Spring 3.1) instead of the `hibernate3` package.

---

Btw: Update the system step by step, but not all at once!

For example:

- Update to Hibernate >= 3.2
- Update to spring 2.0 or 2.5
- Update to Hibernate 3.x
- Then update to spring 3.0
- May Replace Hibernate with JPA 2.0
  ( Then update to spring 3.1 (hopefully not so much to change)
- And then to Hibernate 4.0

Comment: Hi Ralph, yes I found the above link in Google. It is due to version mismatch. Then I have to update both spring and hibernate libraries simultaneously.